# Can an Azure DRM protected video be delivered from a VPS?

Tags: enterprise-architecture

I am planning to develop a subscription based Video on Demand android App.

I am planning to host videos on VPS with unlimited free bandwidth. It's said that nothing beats nginx for static hosting. So I've plan to serve videos through nginx with server configuration :

```
- 32 vCPUs @2.4 GHz
- 60 GB Ram
- 1800 GB SSD
```

costing around 200$ a month. The VPS will run just Nginx, database to be hosted on firebase! Also if anyone could tell me how many concurrent streaming user devices could this configuration handle?

So my Question is, Is is possible that I DRM encode/encrypt locally & serve through vps so that only the Widevine licence fee is paid? which costs [$0.20/100 licenses listed here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/media-services/)

Update:

[This article describes how you can use Media Services to deliver PlayReady and/or Widevine licenses but do the rest with your on-premises servers.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-deliver-keys-and-licenses)